# Angular + Bootstrap dropdown is not working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using Angular 11 for my application [image: application version]

and a bootstrap 4 with angular. All other bootstrap components are working but the dropdown is not working, I installed the bootstrap,jquery, popper.js dependency still dropdown is not working

**Angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "new-application": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/new-application",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "new-application:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "new-application:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "new-application:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "new-application:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "new-application:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "new-application"
}
```

this is the snippet I am using to create the dropdown

```
                     <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown button
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

dropdown is not toggling on the UI even after installing the popper.js dependency

[image: Dropdown]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note :** Before doing this please check your bootstrap version

Simply install `npm i bootstrap` also you can check documentation [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap)

After install Simply add below line in `style.css` file

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

after that add this below link in `index.html` file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Content here -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Checkout more dropdown in bootstrap documentation [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

you can check here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kccg2m?file=src%2Findex.html)

Comment: I just imported the wrong css file in the style.css , thank you it works fine now

Comment: Kiran, what's the purpose of using that in index.html if you're already downloading it using npm and giving the path in angular.json?

Comment: It will work but it is really a bad practice. You are mixing two framework Angular and JQuery for DOM manipulation. There no need to have duplicate importing. Drop down is will show when two classes .show and .d-block is added along to .dropdown